# Usar consulta para almacenar en Array PHP

Tags: html5, mysqli, php7

tengo una consulta y deseo guardar los campos prima anual y valor asegurado en un arreglo como podría realizarlo, ya que solo tengo una base de uno que realice pero no logro que me muestre ningún resultado al momento de imprimirlo, soy nuevo en esto y necesito de su ayuda; Muchas gracias.

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";
$letras_id = $_POST['letras_id'];

$query_select = "SELECT letras.letras_id,letras.valores,letras.planes_id,precios.idprecios,precios.valor_asegurado,precios.prima_anual,precios.letras_opciones, planes.nombre,planes.idplanes,planes.proveedor_id from precios INNER JOIN letras on letras_opciones = letras_id INNER JOIN planes on idplanes = planes_id WHERE letras_ocpiones = '$letras_id'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$query_select);

$resultado_consulta = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

$datos = array(
    'prima_anual' => $resultado_consulta['prima_anual'],
    'valor_asegurado' => $resultado_consulta['valor_asegurado'], 
);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La base para esto, es recorrer el resultado y guardarlo en un array...
De este modo...

```
$query = "SELECT algo FROM esto";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$array = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $algo = $row["algo"];
    array_push($array, $algo);
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Como podria imprimirlos con ajax en inputs ? $("#valor_asegurado").val(dato[0]);

Comment: Ese problema difiere de este amigo, debes crear otro post.